# find numbers and save to string

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a ui that gets the session id of a computer on the network. I want to take this session id and save it to a string to be used later.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ComputerName = ComputerNameBox.Text;
        string Username = UserNameBox.Text;

        Process Process = new Process();
        Process.StartInfo.FileName = "CMD.exe";
        Process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/K" + "qwinsta /server:" + ComputerName + " " + Username;
        Process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        Process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        Process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        Process.Start();

        Process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(SortOutputHandler);

        Process.BeginOutputReadLine();
        while (!Process.HasExited)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
        }

    }
    private void SortOutputHandler(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
    {
        if (MessagePop.InvokeRequired)
        {
            MessagePop.BeginInvoke(new DataReceivedEventHandler(SortOutputHandler), new[] { sendingProcess, outLine });
        }
        else
        {
            MessagePop.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + outLine.Data);
        }
    }
```

This code runs and inputs the computername and username of the computer/person you want the session ID for. The username and ID will likely be different every time so I can't hard code it.

```
SESSIONNAME       USERNAME                 ID  STATE   TYPE        DEVICE
console           mlynch                    9  Active
```

This is the output I get in the textbox, I want to get the 9 and save it to a string, however, the number can be something like 10 or higher so I will need to be able to get both numbers. How do I do this?

Comment: Split the textbox output (by using string.Split) two times (first on NewLine and then on tabs or spaces) to string collection. And then you can iterator the string collection and use int.TryParse to retrieve the integer value.

Comment: Found my answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59274974/find-specific-text-in-richtextbox-and-set-it-to-a-string-c-sharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do what I needed.

```
                Process GetSessionID = new Process();
                GetSessionID.StartInfo.FileName = "CMD.exe";
                GetSessionID.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C" + "for /f \"skip=1 tokens=3\" %1 in ('query user " + Username + "/server:" + ComputerName + "') do @echo %1";
                GetSessionID.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                GetSessionID.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                GetSessionID.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                GetSessionID.Start();
                SessionIDOutput = GetSessionID.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                GetSessionID.WaitForExit();
                DoAllTheThingsTextBox.Text = SessionIDOutput;
                if (GetSessionID.HasExited == true)
                {
                    var digitArray = DoAllTheThingsTextBox.Text.Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray();
                    SessionID = new String(digitArray);

                    if (MouseControlCheck.Checked == true)
                    {
                        Process Process = new Process();
                        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("CMD.exe", "/C" + "mstsc /shadow:" + SessionID + " /v " + ComputerName + " /control");
                        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

                        Process = Process.Start(startInfo);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Process Process = new Process();
                        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("CMD.exe", "/C" + "mstsc /shadow:" + SessionID + " /v " + ComputerName);
                        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

                        Process = Process.Start(startInfo);
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
var textBoxData =
                "SESSIONNAME       USERNAME                 ID  STATE   TYPE        DEVICE\r\nconsole           mlynch                    9  Active";
            var stringCollection = textBoxData.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine, "  " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            var finalCollection = new List<int>();
            foreach (var s1 in stringCollection)
            {
                int n;
                if (int.TryParse(s1, out n))
                {
                    finalCollection.Add(n);
                }
            }
```

(or) create a function which takes in text box data and return int colleciton:

```
public List<int> GetData(string textBoxData)
{
        var stringCollection = textBoxData.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine, "  " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        var finalCollection = new List<int>();
        foreach (var s1 in stringCollection)
        {
            int n;
            if (int.TryParse(s1, out n))
            {
                finalCollection.Add(n);
            }
        }
}
```

and then use it as

```
var intCollection = GetData(textBox1.Text);
```

Comment: Here is the problem, the example text I used will not be the only output. Say I logged out and back in, the session ID changes or say I run this on someone else, the username and id would be different.

Comment: I used hard-coded data from your description just to make sure the code works. Please remove the hard coding and have the logic in a function that takes your textbox data as input parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I get in trouble for linking to my open source project UltimateHelper, but just pretend Word is a string.

```
   public static List<Word> GetWords(string sourceText, char[] delimiters = null)
            {
                // initial value
                List<Word> words = new List<Word>();

                // typical delimiter characters
                char[] delimiterChars = { ' ', '-', '/', ',', '.', ':', '\t' };

                // if the delimiters exists
                if (delimiters != null)
                {
                    // use the delimiters passedin
                    delimiterChars = delimiters;
                }

                // verify the sourceText exists
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sourceText))
                {
                    // Get the list of strings
                    string[] strings = sourceText.Split(delimiterChars);

                    // now iterate the strings
                    foreach (string stringWord in strings)
                    {
                        // verify the word is not an empty string or a space
                        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(stringWord))
                        {
                            // Create a new Word
                            Word word = new Word(stringWord);

                            // now add this word to words collection
                            words.Add(word);
                        }
                    }
                }

                // return value
                return words;
            }
```

I have this in a class called WordParser, so to call it:

Edit: If you need to parse each line, there is also a method:

```
List<TextLine> textLines = WordParser.GetTextLines(text);
```

In your case, you want to parse on just space, so set Delimiters to this:

```
char[] delimiterChars = { ' ' };

List<Word> words = WordParser.GetWords(text, delimiterChars);

// Here is the full example using DataJuggler.Core.UltimateHelper Nuget package
if ((ListHelper.HasOneOrMoreItems(words)) && (words.Count >= 3))
{
   Word idWord = Words[2];
   int idValue = NumericHelper.ParseInteger(idWord.Text, 0, -1);   
}
```

idValue will be the Id if it parses, 0 if it can't be parsed, and -1 if an error occurs trying to parse it.

I hope I didn't offend anyone by not posting all the classes used, but if it does I will post the full class for each, but kind of overkill to demonstrate a 3 line of code solution.

Hope it helps.

The full code is here: 
https://github.com/DataJuggler/UltimateHelper/tree/master/UltimateHelper

And Word Parser:
https://github.com/DataJuggler/UltimateHelper/blob/master/UltimateHelper/WordParser.cs

Word class:
https://github.com/DataJuggler/UltimateHelper/blob/master/UltimateHelper/Objects/Word.cs

List Helper:
https://github.com/DataJuggler/UltimateHelper/blob/master/UltimateHelper/ListHelper.cs

And Numeric Helper:
https://github.com/DataJuggler/UltimateHelper/blob/master/UltimateHelper/NumericHelper.cs