# Find specific text in RichTextBox and set it to a string c#

Tags: c#

I am at a loss as to how to do this. I am printing some information to a richtextbox that will be multiple lines, has words and numbers. I need to search the richtextbox for specific numbers and if they are there, set them to a string to be used later. Say the box contains `User: Matt  User's number: 9` I want to have a string labeled `UserNum` so that I can have something like `Messagebox.Show("The User's Number is " + UserNum);` and have it show up as `The User's Number is 9`.

Originally I thought this would work...

```
if (richtextbox1.Text.Contains(" 9") == true)
{
    UserNum = "9";
    Messagebox.Show("The User's Number is " + UserNum);
}
```

How could I go about doing this? The name and number will be on the same line and the name will be varying lengths so I can't just have it look at a set spot in the box. The number itself also can range from 1 to 30 so I would need to either repeat an if command 30 times or put a range.

Edit: There is potential for there to be other lines that might also contain numbers outside of the 1-30 range.

Comment: With your edit: So are you trying to catch all numbers between range, the first number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like regular expressions might be useful here. Otherwise, if you know there will only be one number in the textbox, you could select all the chars that are digits and initialize a new string from the array:

```
var digitArray = richtextbox1.Text.Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray();
string userNum = new String(digitArray);
Messagebox.Show("The User's Number is " + userNum);
```

Comment: The is potential for there to be multiple numbers but none that fall in the 1-30 range.

Comment: In that case, if the other numbers will always be other lines, I would split the text on the newLine char, loop through the array finding all the numbers, and return the first one >= 1 and <= 30.

Answer (score 1):

With regex, you can have:

```
string pattern = @"[0-9]+";
string input = @"Matt's number for today 
is 33 and OK.";
RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;

Console.WriteLine("Matt's number is: {0}", Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options)[0].Value);
```

Comment: I prefer this solution over mine!

Comment: So how do you enforce upper and lower ranges on this regex logic? Or if there is no numeric value? Asking for a friend of course.

Comment: @TravisActon For something like 30, you can have `string pattern = @"(30|[1-9]|[1-2][0-9])";`

Comment: So that still doesn't solve the issue since your regex is parsing by char and not full string. For example, if Matt's number is 12 then you are going to output that his number is 1. If his number is 62 then you are going to output his number is 6.

Comment: A simple reverse logic will solve that `string pattern = @"(30|[1-2][0-9]|[1-9])";`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Linq query to find the number like below:

```
var nums = Enumerable.Range(1,30).Select(x => x.ToString());
var num = richtextbox1.Text.Split(' ')
                      .Where(x => numStr.Contains(x))
                      .Single();
Console.WriteLine("The user number is " + num);
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Use String.Split to parse the string into an array
2. Iterate array and use Int32.TrParse method to determine if the "word" is in fact a number

   ```
       var input = "User: Matt  User's number: 10";
       int num = 0;
       foreach(var word in input.Split(' '))
       {
           if (Int32.TryParse(word, out num) && Enumerable.Range(1,30).Contains(num))
           {
               Console.WriteLine("The user number is " + num);
               break;
           }
       }
   ```

or with linq:

```
        int testNum;
        var digits = input.Split(' ').Where(a => Int32.TryParse(a, out testNum) && Enumerable.Range(1, 30).Contains(testNum)).FirstOrDefault();
        Console.WriteLine("Linq The user number is " + (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(digits) ? digits : "Not Found"));
```